# What happens to survivors resources when they join your group?

Tags: state-of-decay, state-of-decay-breakdown

So I'm back into playing State of Decay and I always wondered, when a group of survivors wants to join your group, what happens to any resources in their "chest"... does it go to you?  Or does it just get lost forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They disappear, so if you need the items, empty their "chest" first, before you let them join your crew.

I tested it with an empty account.